# Numpy: Accessing sub ndarrays with multiple index lists

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am trying to access (more precisely: add to) a subset of a numpy array using multiple index lists.
However, what is working perfectly with slices, does not work as expected using arbitrary index lists:

```
import numpy as np

# this one works:

A_4th_order = np.zeros( (4,2,4,2) )

sub_a = np.ones( (3,1,3,1) )

i = k = slice(0,3)
j = l = slice(1,2)

A_4th_order[i,j,k,l] += sub_a


# this one doesn't:

B_4th_order = np.zeros( (4,2,4,2) )

sub_b = np.ones( (3,1,3,1) )

i = k = np.array([0,1,2], dtype=int)
j = l = np.array([1], dtype=int)

B_4th_order[i,j,k,l] += sub_b
```

How can I achieve this operation in an efficient and readable manner?

Comment: what's the error when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the the shapes just before performing the in place update, you see the following:

```py
>>> print(A_4th_order[i, j, k, l].shape)
(3, 1, 3, 1)
```

And:

```py
>>> print(B_4th_order[i, j, k, l].shape)
(3,)
```

In the first case the sub-array is 4d, while in the second case it is 1d. This is because your coordinate arrays `i, j, k, l` are 1d arrays. Once you transform the arrays into an open mesh, for example using `np.ix_`, it works as expected:

```py
import numpy as np

# this one works:

A_4th_order = np.zeros((4, 2, 4, 2))

sub_a = np.ones((3, 1, 3, 1))

i = k = slice(0, 3)
j = l = slice(1, 2)

print(A_4th_order[i, j, k, l].shape)
A_4th_order[i, j, k, l] += sub_a

# this one doesn't:

B_4th_order = np.zeros((4, 2, 4, 2))

sub_b = np.ones((3, 1, 3, 1))

i = k = np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int)
j = l = np.array([1,], dtype=int)

# transform into an open meshgrid
i, j, k, l = np.ix_(i, j, k, l)

print(B_4th_order[i, j, k, l].shape)
B_4th_order[i, j, k, l] += sub_b

np.allclose(A_4th_order, B_4th_order)
```

After applying `np.ix_`, the `i, j, k, l` coordinate arrays have shapes corresponding to their respective dimension, they apply to:

```py
>>> print(i.shape)
>>> print(j.shape)
>>> print(k.shape)
>>> print(l.shape)
(3, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 3, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That helps and makes perfectly sense! Thank you very much.